# How to do a search query in two fields one an int on a string

Tags: database, string, jsf, int, derby

i don't know if this is possible so i thought i would post here

is it possible to have one input box and if for example a user enters a string or an int it will search two columns of the database, the i.d. (int) and the username (string), how could i pass this to be searching from the view, as i set the type to be an int or string in the getters etc but how could i do this if i wanted to search for both types ?

this is how i am currently am searching the db for an int

```
 <h:inputText id="search" value="#{userdetailsController.search}"  />   
                    &nbsp;


                    <p:commandButton value="Search" action="#{userdetailsController.submit}" update="group" />
```

the userdetailsController

```
private String search;

    private List<Userdetails> item; // No need for DataModel here.

    public List<Userdetails> getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public String submit() {
        item = ejbFacade.searchByString(search);
        return ""; //change this !, testing only
    }

    public String getSearch() {
        return search;
    }

    public void setSearch(String search) {
        this.search = search;
    }
```

and in the userdetails

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "Userdetails.searchByUsername", query = "SELECT u FROM Userdetails u WHERE u.username like :username")
```

thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep the property a `String` and check in the action method if it represents a number.

E.g.

```
public void submit() {
    if (search.matches("[0-9]+")) {
        item = ejbFacade.searchByInt(Integer.parseInt(search));
    } else {
        item = ejbFacade.searchByString(search);
    }
}
```

You could alternatively also handle it in the service method itself, that depends on how reusable you want the service to be. Services (EJBs) can namely also be used by other frontends than JSF, such as JAX-RS (RESTFul), plain Servlets/Filters, etc.

```
public void submit() {
    item = ejbFacade.search(search);
}
```

with

```
public List<Userdetail> search(String query) {
    if (query.matches("[0-9]+")) {
        return searchByInt(Integer.parseInt(query));
    } else {
        return searchByString(query);
    }
}
```